# Get exact match

Tags: php, sql

I want to find usernames and passwords of exact match, but these queries let me log in even if I write the first characters of the values(for instance, if the password is "jelly", just writing "jel" will let me log in). What's the problem?

```
    //conn db
    $conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

    /* check connection */
    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    //query
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT userName FROM Users WHERE userName='" . $_POST["user"] . "'");

    //verif user
    if (!$result->num_rows) {
        echo '<span>Username ' . $_POST["user"] . ' doesn\'t exist in the database. Do you want to  <a class="underl" href="register.php">register a new one?</a></span><br>';
    } //verific daca parola e buna(+recover pass)
    //parola goala?
    else if (empty($_POST["pwd"])) echo '<span>Please enter the password associated to your username to log in. If you forgot it you can <a class="underl" href="recover.php">recover it.</a></span><br>';
    else {//verific daca parola e buna
        /* free result set */
        $result->close();
        //query
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM Users WHERE password='" . $_POST["pwd"] . "'");
        //verif
        if (!$result->num_rows)
            echo '<span>Entered password doesn\'t match for the username ' . $_POST["user"] . '. If you forgot it you can <a class="underl" href="recover.php">recover it.</a></span><br>';
else //login...}
```

Comment: You appear to be logging people in if their username or password exist, but not necessarily on the same user. For instance, I could create an account, then put in your username and my password and have it work.

Comment: I want to check them sepparately. In this order:empty user->user exists->empty password->wrong password->success.

Comment: @George Irimiciuc, You shouldn't do that. If either is wrong just give the user a generic "username or password wrong". What you're doing will allow them to compile a list of all usernames in the system. Bad idea.

Comment: Why is it bad? The generic irritates me personally, I thought it would be more comfortable this way.

Comment: @developerwjk I have to agree, why is it bad? If you go on my site's forums, you see everyone's usernames clear as day. What you're suggesting is security through obscurity, and it's deliberately hindering user experience for no valid reason that I can discern.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, It depends on the site I guess. But you might not want a list of your users to be compiled in some cases. Doesn't necessarily have to be about security so much as proprietary information.

Comment: @developerwjk If the "username" were the user's email address, then yes I agree there's a problem with telling people if the entered address is a valid user. However, usernames are (typically) non-personally-identifying - that's why they're shown on out comments here, are they not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query knows nothing about which user you're checking against. This pretty much allows the user to log in as anyone if they know at least 1 password in the db.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM Users WHERE password='" . $_POST["pwd"] . "' AND username = '...'");
```

Comment: And indeed, one of the passwords existing in the database was starting the same as the one I was checking.

Comment: To expand a little, the "correct" approach is to load the user's data by their username (if they exist, of course), and then check if that user's password matches the one given.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol agreed. I wouldn't ever select a password from a db just from a security perspective, but I don't know the OP's motive.